# Mono supporting arm64 architecture on Android?

Tags: android, mono

Sorry for my bad english...
Is Mono supporting arm64 architecture on Android? I am asking because I need loading assemblies at runtime on 64 bit Android. If yes, which version?

Comment: Do you mean Xamarin?

Comment: Yes, i does (i.e. `Xamarin.Android` uses it as its runtime)